# Magento 2 module, Model - problem

Tags: magento2

I am making form in front end and want to save data in database in Magento 2, i have used below code but when i am using link page shows Blank

> My/Module/Block/contact.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Block;

/**
 * Test content block
*/
class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Simple Custom Module'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

> My/Module/Controller/index/contact.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use My\Module\Model\SaveFactory;
class contact extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Save
     */
    protected $_save;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SaveFactory $save
    ) {
        $this->_contact = $save;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $save = $this->_contact->create();
        $save->setData($data);
        if($save->save()){
             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect =  $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('mymodule/index/contact');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

> My/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Module" setup_version="1.1.0" />
</config>
```

> My/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="My_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> My/Module/Model/Save.php

```
<?php 
namespace My\Module\Model;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save");
    }
}
?>
```

> My/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Save.php

```
<?php 
namespace My\Module\Model\ResourceModel;
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("my_module_post","id");
    }
}
?>
```

> My/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Module/Collection.php

```
<?php 
namespace My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save;
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("My\Module\Model\Save","My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save");
    }
}
?>
```

> My/Module/view/registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'My_Module',
    __DIR__
    );
```

> My/Module/view/frontend/layout/mymodule_index_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>HTML title - The contact form page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="My\Module\Block\Contact" name="mymodule_contact" template="My_Module::contact.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> My/Module/view/frontend/templates/contact.phtml

```
<h1>Contact page</h1>
<form class="" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'mymodule/index/contact'; ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text">
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Send contact informations">
</form>
```

AND URL IS
http://192.168.1.107/magento231/mymodule/index/contact

Comment: http://192.168.1.107/magento231/mymodule/index/contact This is your form page url?

Comment: yes, I am Using That URL

Comment: And what is the url for save? Its same? Are you getting error during form page load or saving data?

Comment: During the page Load, Yes Its same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change 2 files and add one more file to save data. Follow the below instruction to get result.

Change the file:

> My/Module/Controller/Index/Contact.php

with content:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ){
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

And file:

> My/Module/view/frontend/templates/contact.phtml

with content:

```
<h1>Contact page</h1>

<form class="" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'mymodule/index/save'; ?>" method="post">
<input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" type="text">
<input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" type="text">
<input name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text">
<input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
<input type="submit" value="Send contact informations">
</form>
```

And add one more file:

> My/Module/Controller/Index/Save.php

with content:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use My\Module\Model\SaveFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Save
     */
    protected $_save;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        SaveFactory $save
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_contact = $save;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $request = $this->request->getParams();
        $save = $this->_contact->create();
        $save->setData($data);
        if($save->save()){
             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect =  $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('mymodule/index/contact');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Now run di:compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: Thanks, Its Worked very well , Can you explain me what we have done here, I am new to Magento 2

Comment: I have created separate controller class for save action and form page url. And in the form page url simply call the page and in the save action gettting post data by http request and save that to the table through your Model class.

Comment: Okay ,Thank you for Support

Comment: Welcome and Happy coding!